# Can't parse the names from the third page onward

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've created a script in python using requests module and BeautifulSoup library to fetch the name of different members from a website. The script can fetch the name from the first page and the second page flawlessly. However, it scrapes the same names from the third page onward. What I could notice that the next page logic is within the value of `__EVENTTARGET`, as in `dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$grdMembers$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl07` and `dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$grdMembers$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl09` and so on. The script can increment the numbers accordingly but the result after page two stays the same.

To populate the results from this [website](https://www.icsi.in/student/Members/MemberSearch.aspx?SkinSrc=%5BG%5DSkins/IcsiTheme/IcsiIn-Bare&ContainerSrc=%5BG%5DContainers/IcsiTheme/NoContainer), all you need to do is click on the search button without changing anything. You can then click on the 2,3,4 e.t.c pages to go on to the concerning page.

I've tried with (scraping data from the first two pages):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.icsi.in/student/Members/MemberSearch.aspx?SkinSrc=%5BG%5DSkins/IcsiTheme/IcsiIn-Bare&ContainerSrc=%5BG%5DContainers/IcsiTheme/NoContainer'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml") 
    payload = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
    payload['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$btnSearch'

    page = 5
    while True:
        r = s.post(link,data=payload)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
        for item in soup.select("span[id$='_lblFullName']"):
            print(item.text)

        page+=2
        payload = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
        if len(str(page))==1:
            payload['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$grdMembers$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl0{}'.format(page)
        else:
            payload['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$grdMembers$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl{}'.format(page)

        payload['__dnnVariable'] = {'__scdoff':'1','__dnn_pageload':'__dnn_setScrollTop();'}
        payload['ScrollTop'] = '400'
```

> How can I fetch the names from the rest of the pages after the second page?

Comment: it seems Like ASP.NET page - it can send many POST values - not only `__EVENTTARGET` - and you may have to send all of them - also as `POST` request. FIRTS: use DevTools in Firefox/Chrome to see all requests send from browser when you go to next page - and see what values it sends, and if it `GET` or `POST` request. Your code has to send the same.

Comment: I'm sending probably all of them. If you print payload you can see the required parameters present in there. Thanks.

Comment: BTW you can use `"{:02}".format(7)` to get `07` instead of `7` and then you don't have to check `if len(str(page))==1:` (BTW: instead `if len(str(page))==1:` you could simply check `if page < 10:`)

Comment: when I check `payload.keys()` and compare with keys send in web browser then I see keys which browser doesn't send - ie. keys for buttons with arrows (to move to first/last/previous/next page) and maybe it makes problem. ie. `dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$grdMembers$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl02` for button which moves to first page.

Comment: I added this line `payload.pop('dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$grdMembers$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl02')` at the bottom of the while loop to kick out the key from payload but that doesn't seem to fix the issues. Thanks.

Comment: but there can be many other  names  because there are other buttons ie. I saw `...ctl28` for arrow to next page (but I'm not sure if it doesn't use different name if there is less pages to display). I'm not sure but pages can also use JavaScript to calculate `__EVENTVALIDATION` and server can check it - but `requests`/`bs4` can't run JavaScript.

Comment: @MITHU check below answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It starts working if I remove from payload keys like `dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$grdMembers$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl02` which are keys for arrow buttons.

```
    name_length = len('dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$grdMembers$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl02')

    for key in list(payload.keys()):
        if key.startswith('dnn') and len(key) == name_length:
            payload.pop(key)
            print(key)
```

but you could use method from `αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη` answer to make sure you send only needed values.

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.icsi.in/student/Members/MemberSearch.aspx?SkinSrc=%5BG%5DSkins/IcsiTheme/IcsiIn-Bare&ContainerSrc=%5BG%5DContainers/IcsiTheme/NoContainer'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")

    payload = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
    payload['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$btnSearch'

    page = 5
    while True:

        r = s.post(link, data=payload)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
        for item in soup.select("span[id$='_lblFullName']"):
            print(item.text)

        page += 2

        payload = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
        payload['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$grdMembers$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl{:02}'.format(page)

        name_length = len('dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$grdMembers$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl02')
        for key in list(payload.keys()):
            if key.startswith('dnn') and len(key) == name_length:
                payload.pop(key)
                print(key)

        payload['__dnnVariable'] = {'__scdoff':'1','__dnn_pageload':'__dnn_setScrollTop();'}
        payload['ScrollTop'] = '400'
```

---

**EDIT:** page uses more complex system and after 10 pages it display new links but with old values `ctl07`, `ctl09`. Instead of this links I use name from button with arrow to next page - at start it has value `ctrl28` but after 10 pages it has `ctrl30` (because there are more links - it adds links `...` to next/previous list of 10 pages)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.icsi.in/student/Members/MemberSearch.aspx?SkinSrc=%5BG%5DSkins/IcsiTheme/IcsiIn-Bare&ContainerSrc=%5BG%5DContainers/IcsiTheme/NoContainer'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")

    payload = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}
    payload['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$btnSearch'

    page = 1  # I don't need it to generate lins, now I use it only to display page number
    while True:
        print('page:', page)
        page += 1

        r = s.post(link, data=payload)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
        for item in soup.select("span[id$='_lblFullName']"):
            print(item.text)

        payload = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}

        name_length = len('dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$grdMembers$ctl00$ctl02$ctl01$ctl28')
        for key in list(payload.keys()):
            if key.startswith('dnn') and len(key) == name_length:
                payload.pop(key)
                #print(key)

        # button with arrow to next page

        next_page = soup.select("input[class='rgPageNext']")
        if not next_page:
            break

        next_page = next_page[0]['name']
        print(next_page)
        payload[next_page] = ''

        payload['__dnnVariable'] = {'__scdoff':'1','__dnn_pageload':'__dnn_setScrollTop();'}
        payload['ScrollTop'] = '400'
```

Comment: After 12 or 13 pages the script starts producing the results of earlier page repeatedly.

Comment: did you check it in web browser? Probably it use different values then you expect. Now I checked link to page 11 and it uses again `ctl07` instead of `ctl25` - so it works different then we could expect.

Comment: instead of generating value for `'__EVENTTARGET'` I used name from `select("input[class='rgPageNext']")[0]['name']`  (button with arrow to next page) and then I get correct values even after 10 pages.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you were needing to include the full post `Payload` parameters.

We have to done that within the same `Session` using `requests.Session()` as the website pagination is using a rotate `function` based on `__dnnVariable` which the server receive it under `JS` request which is translated to Loop.

Where it's actually meaning `Next`

So, I've made a `GET` request firstly and fetched required `params` (some of them is dynamic and other is static)

Then, I made a post request under the same `session`

```py
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import unquote

data = {
    '__EVENTTARGET': "dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$btnSearch",
    '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
    '__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED': '',
    'dnn$ctlHeader$dnnSearch$Search': 'SiteRadioButton',
    'dnn$ctlHeader$dnnSearch$txtSearch': '',
    'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtFirstName': '',
    'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtLastName': '',
    'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$ddlMemberType': 0,
    'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtMembershipNumber': '',
    'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtCpNumber': '',
    'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtCity': '',
    'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtOrganisation': '',
    'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtAddress2': '',
    'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtAddress3': '',
    'dnn$ctr410$MemberSearch$txtEmail': '',
    'dnn_ctr410_MemberSearch_grdMembers_ClientState': '',
    'ScrollTop': 432,
    '__dnnVariable': '{"__scdoff":"1","__dnn_pageload":"__dnn_setScrollTop();"}'
}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        r = req.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        data['StylesheetManager_TSSM'] = re.search(
            r"hf.value \+= '(.*?)\'", r.text).group(1)
        data['ScriptManager_TSM'] = unquote(soup.findAll('script', src=True)
                                            [2]['src']).split("=", 3)[-1]
        data['__VIEWSTATE'] = soup.find("input", id="__VIEWSTATE").get("value")
        data['__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'] = soup.find(
            "input", id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR").get("value")
        data['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = soup.find(
            "input", id="__EVENTVALIDATION").get("value")

        for _ in range(10):
            r = req.post(url, data=data)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
            names = [name.text for name in soup.select("div.name_head")]
            page = soup.select_one(
                "a.rgCurrentPage").next_sibling['href'].split("'")[1]
            data['__EVENTTARGET'] = page
            data['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = soup.find(
                "input", id="__EVENTVALIDATION").get("value")
            data['__VIEWSTATE'] = soup.find(
                "input", id="__VIEWSTATE").get("value")
            print(names)


main("https://www.icsi.in/student/Members/MemberSearch.aspx")
```

> Note: on each request you will get the data not in sort order since the `search` function is using `random` on the back-end server.

Output:

```
['SH. DILIP RAGHUNATH KOTWAL', 'SH. ARUNODAY ROY MUKHERJEE', 'SH. J SUBRAMANI', 'SH. R KRISHNAMANI', 'SH. R NARAYANASWAMI', 'SH. M V GOPALAKRISHNAN', 'SH. RAJAM KRISHNAMURTHY', 'SH. V SIVASUBRAMANIAN', 'SH. V RAGHAVENDRAN', 'SH. G V AIMAN']
['SH. K J MATHEW', 'SH. K K GHOSH', 'SH. SUBHASH CHANDER DHAWAN', 'SH. BABU RAM MAHESWARI', 'SH. S SWAMINATHAN', 'SH. T S A AIYER', 'SH. KOVILOOR VIJAYARAGHAVACHARI SAMPATHKUMAR', 'SH. M KRISHNAN', 'SH. R N BANSAL', 'SH. N V RAMAN']
['SH. R VENKATARAMANI', 'SH. UTPALENDU ROY CHOUDHURY', 'SH. LAKSHMI NARAYANAN V', 'SH. PARIJAT KUMAR HORE', 'SH. B R VENKATESAN', 'SH. KISHAN GOPAL SOMANI', 'SH. O P GANERIWALA', 'SH. P T KUPPUSWAMY', 'SH. U P MATHUR', 'SH. N N UPADHYAY']
['SH. N K BHANDARI', 'SH. S R C SETTY', 'SH. S V BALASUBRAMANIAN', 'SH. HOSHIE HIRJI MALGHAM', 'SH. KAIKOBAD SORABJI ITALIA', 'SH. K SIVADAS', 'SH. K K SIVARAMAKRISHNAN', 'SH. A CHANDRASEKARAN', 'SH. R PONNAMBALAM', 'SH. T K B VENKATARAMAN']
['SH. NARINDER PAL', 'SH. PARKASH ATAM', 'SH. K A PARTHASARATHY', 'SH. SURESH CHANDRA OSWAL', 'SH. MAHENDRA KANTILAL SHAH', 'SH. V. SANTHANAKRISHNA', 'SH. VASANT NARAYAN GOGATE', 'SH. MANEKLAL 
PATEL', 'SH. B N VISHWANATH', 'SH. B S L NARAYAN']
['SH. P L N VIJAYANAGAR', 'SH. SHREEPAD MARTAND  KORDE', 'SH. SHIV BHAGWAN KOTHARI', 'SH. R B POPLAI', 'SH. RAMESH KHANNA', 'SH. RAVINDER NATH JOSHI', 'SH. VIDYA SAGAR AGGARWAL', 'SH. ARVIND JAYKUMAR CHAKOTE', 'SH. V RAMASESHAN', 'SH. BADRINARAYAN BALDAWA']
['SH. C GOVINDANKUTTY', 'SH. A G MADHAVAN', 'SH. DHIRAJ NATH BHATTACHARYYA', 'SH. RAMESHWAR LAL INANI', 'SH. RAMESHWARDAS C DAGA', 'SH. R SUBRAMANIAN', 'SH. S M REGE', 'SH. NARENDRA KUMAR KAPOOR', 'SH. K RAMAMURTHI', 'SH. ROOPENDRA NARAYAN ROY']
['SH. KALYAN KUMAR MITRA', 'SH. KALYANASUNDARAM ', 'SH. N A SESHADRI', 'SH. RAJENDRA KUMAR JAIN', 'SH. BISWAJIT SEN', 'SH. RAMKRISHNA NATHOOMAL  AGRAWAL', 'SH. P C SHETH', 'SH. K S NATARAJAN', 
'SH. S N DAMLE', 'SH. A M FADIA']
['DR. K N M RAO', 'SH. IYER M. RAMASWAMY', 'SH. DILIP KANTI MAZUMDAR', 'SH. RAM CHANDRA NIGAM', 'SH. SUBRAHMANIAM VISWANATHAN', 'SH. SURESH KUMAR JERATH', 'SH. A Y SRINIVASAN', 'DR. S C GARG', 
'SH. CHANDRA PRAKASH SHARDA', 'SH. M P JAIN']
['SH. E S DWARKANATH', 'SH. MYSORE SHAMANNA  RAMACHANDRA', 'SH. SUBHASH CHANDER SINGHAL', 'SH. T T SINHA', 'SH. G R BHANDARI', 'SH. M P GOEL', 'SH. CHOKKANATHAPURAM SUBRAMANIAN  NATESAN', 'SH. 
V M PATEL', 'SH. BIJOY KUMAR AGARWALLA', 'SH. BAHADUR CHAND JAIN']
```

Comment: Yeah, both of your solutions work. Thanks a trillion.